# Enviar EMAIL em IONIC/angular gera um erro de Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, alguem sabe o motivo?

Tags: ionic

**home.page.html**

```
  <ion-icon name="Send" size="small"></ion-icon>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click) ="sendEmail()">
      Send Email
    </button>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
sendEmail() {
    this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{
      if(available) {

        let email = {
          to: 'emiliodami@gmail.com',
          attachments: [
          ],
          subject: 'Started service order',
          body: 'Foi aberto a ordem',
          isHtml: true
        }

      // Send a text message using default options
      this.emailComposer.open(email);
      }     

    })  
  }
```

**erro:**

```
PicturesPage.html:24 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at PicturesPage.push../src/app/pictures/pictures.page.ts.PicturesPage.sendEmail (pictures.page.ts:69)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (PicturesPage.html:24)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
    at core.js:21003
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
```

**Uma rotina simples de envio de email e não sei encontrar solução, alguem sabe porque acontece esse erro?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estou usando dessa forma e sem erros. Ele me permite escolher qual aplicativo de e-mail enviar.

```
send() {
let email = {
  to: this.to,
  cc: [],
  bcc: [],
  attachment: [],
  subject: this.subject,
  body: this.body,
  isHtml: false,
  app: ""
}
this.emailComposer.open(email);
```

}